# Subversive plugin does not show up in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins

I'm using eclipse Mars 2 and installed the SVN Team Provider plugin from the Luna repository cause mars's repository ended up giving me an error that it couldn't install. Now i face the problem of being unable to install a SVN Connector cause eclipse doesn't give me the ability to create a new SVN project or repository. Actually the whole IDE does not show any sign of SVN being installed except for the installed software window.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Subversive through the Eclipse Marketplace.  When I did that I was given a option to install the Connector.  If that doesn't work you can try the software site by going to

Help >> Install New Software >> Add...

Give it a name and paste this site to install svn.

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/3.0/update-site/

Once it is installed you can go to

Window >>  Show view >> other...

In the search box type SVN and you should have some options.